# Free chemical reactions database

Tags: software, databases

I'm creating a program, which predicts reactions of compound. So, I need a database of chemical reactions. And I need both inorganic and organic reactions. But I can't use Scifinder or Reaxys because they are not free. Is there any free analogs?

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/46725/4945 http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/22285/4945 http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/55937/4945 http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/4040/4945

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the current form the question is addressed, and assuming you took a look at a listing of software already in the field like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer-assisted_organic_synthesis_software), I speculate the sheer number of organic reactions ([just some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_organic_reactions)) alone renders such a task as a one-man / one-woman project too large.  There is a lot of work associated to create such a database, or software. [Organic Synthesis](http://www.orgsyn.org/) is one open-access reference for organic reactions, yet the normal output is a html / pdf of the *reaction procedure*, and not a [*.sdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_table_file#SDF) (or other chemically relevant *.xml-like) format.  [Inorganic Synthesis](http://www.inorgsynth.com/) is a publication with similar intent as the former, yet not openly accessible.

Nevertheless, if you are interested in this topic, I suggest to consult the recent publications *Computer-aided synthesis design: 40 years on* ([DOI 10.1002/wcms.61](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/wcms.61/full)) as well as the just about a year old *Computer-Assisted Synthetic Planning: The End of the Beginning* in *Angewandte Chemie* ([English version DOI: 10.1002/anie.201506101](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/anie.201506101/abstract)).

Comment: Thank you a lot for links: they are very helpful. But as I understand, in Organic Syntesis procedures of reactions are described. Are there any database where only reactions are presented, e.g. "CH4+2O2->CO2+2H2O"?

Comment: Beside "the two" (referring Chemical Abstracts by ACS, and Reaxys/Beilstein by Elsevier; both behind a paywall) used day-in day-out, I assume Martin's comment (+1 is not enough) is really a treasure chest worth to explore more in detail.  RSC's *Methods in Organic Synthesis* (http://pubs.rsc.org/lus/methods-in-organic-synthesis) still allows *manual* download of single entries as *.cdx which you might convert with openbabel and eventually process further.  As back "old days" Isisbase (MDL) was a program to maintain locally a literature collection allowing to search by chemical structure.

Comment: I speculate, facing a new substrate,  in the end such a software "simply" looks for pattern "typical" for reactions already trained / encoded, similar to E. J. Corey's red book "The logic of chemical synthesis".  By virtue of computational power, more rapidly; perhaps even with suggestions no chemist (yet) attempted.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand you - English is not my native language.

Comment: At what point?  I suggest http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56490/chemical-reactions-database

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't answer you in chat: I haven't enough reputation. But I can read.